# Obtaining Global Positioning System related data in Model Derivative translated model

Tags: gps, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

While using the Forge Viewer to visualize BIM models, we were able to confirm that original models placed at GPS coordinate location are properly translated with Model Derivative, making BIM be placed at geo coordinates(or at least, model's global offset with some geo coordinates).

However, we were not able to distinguish whether model derivative translated BIM Models were based on GPS coordinates or not. I was wondering if there exists a flag that provides us that information.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please accept our sincere apologies for the delay, we have a backlog of support cases.

As I know, Forge platform doesn't play well with GIS information currently. Apologizing for any inconvenience caused. Consequently, our InfraWorks team is looking for companies and developers who can help us narrow down the use cases, please refer here for the detail: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/call-input-infraworks-api

However, you can use the following codes to tell the Forge Viewer (after v.3.1) do not centralize models after loading, if your Revit models are placed with some GIS coordinates in Revit shared coordinates system.

```
var loadOptions = {
  applyRefPoint: true,
  globalOffset: { x:0, y:0, z:0 }
};

this.viewer.loadModel(
            svfUrl, 
            loadOptions,
            onLoadModelSuccess,
            onLoadModelError
);
```

Comment: I am using GeoLocationData class in Forge Design Automation, it doesn't work. I wanted to use it to add map image at given latitude longitude in my model and save it as DWG. Is there any possibility of making it available?

I actually checked the GEOGRAPHICLOCATION command in AcCoreConsole. Even though I had loaded the crx, AcCoreConsole showed that it was an invalid command.

Comment: I think this command is not part of the AcCore. I'm checking with our engineering and will get you back A.S.A.P.

Comment: @ashish According to our dev team, the GEOGRAPHICLOCATION command is not supported by AutoCAD Design Automation now. Apologizing for any inconvenience caused.